# How can I rotate a wooden ring and still be able to sand the inner/outer surface by hand?

Tags: wood, sanding

I'm sanding some wooden pull up rings by hand, and I'd like to know of a technique to sand them so that the ring can rotate about its center, but still allow me to grip it with some sand paper in hand for rapid sanding.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pull up rings", could you clarify?

Comment: @Graphus, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rings_(gymnastics)

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification, I was visualising something *completely* different! Something like this is probably best sanded simply with abrasive paper/cloth/sponge wrapped around the ring, gripped with one hand and the ring rotated through the abrasive using the other hand. It'll go surprisingly quickly once you start and get 'in the zone'. Begin with 80 or 100 grit to begin with (depending on what you're starting with) and end at approx. 180 grit. I can't imagine there's much benefit to sanding these to a grit much higher than this either visually or for the required grip. [contd]

Comment: I should mention that, as with all sanding jobs, you could probably speed the process up some if you do some scraping instead of trying to do it all using abrasives. But this requires a concave scraper and the means to put a proper hook on its edge so if you don't already have that just sanding will get the job done.

Comment: One thing I haven't seen mentioned is a sanding mop. There are several variations, and one of them might help speed things up. Also, it appears they could be made fairly easily, depending on the style you want, and what materials you have on hand. I've seen tutorials on making them, but I confess I haven't tried it myself. Even if you use a sanding mop, it may end up being the case that you want or need to do the final sanding by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You could use double-sided tape or hot glue to attach the ring to a jig that rotates on the ring's center.

If you don't attach to the side of the ring, then you will have to use 2 attachment options, one for sanding the inside and one for sanding the outside--which isn't necessarily a bad option, if it is faster.

For example, if you have a lathe and appropriately-sized jaws for your chuck, you could sand the outside, then the inside.

Comment: I was thinking of a three wheel system. Two concave rubber wheels 6" apart, and then attach the third wheel to the power drill. Place the ring on the two wheels, then place the drill wheel in the center of the ring and press down and spin, but that seemed too complicated.

Comment: Kinda like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vI7gE3546Pg) thing, but smaller, made with rubber padded wheels, and for a wood ring instead of a metal bar. I suppose, one way or another, this is going to be complicated.

Comment: It depends on how many you need to make. If you're only making a one-off, it probably doesn't make sense to spend time on a sanding jig. But if you're going to be selling these, it makes more sense to make your process faster and repeatable.